# iOS: GPUImage Trouble Getting ForceProcessingAtSize to Work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, avcapturesession

Currently I am using GPUImage to capture square photos. Everything is working correctly, except for the output size. The output is 2448 x 2448, but I'd like to force it to be 1080 x 1080.

This is my current setup:

```
//Setup Photo Camera
self.photoCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
self.photoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
self.photoCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = YES;

//Setup Crop Filter
self.cropFilter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CroppedCenterRectPhoto];
[self.cropFilter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(1080, 1080)];

//Setup CameraView
self.cameraView = [[GPUImageView alloc] init];

//Add Targets
[self.photoCamera addTarget:self.cropFilter];
[self.cropFilter addTarget:self.cameraView];
self.cameraView.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill;
```

I am using the `-(void)forceProcessingAtSize:` method recommended on several sites, but it's not doing anything. Am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
self.photoCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
```

with

```
self.photoCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
```